# My code is correct but it doesnt run on my vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{  
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*first;

void create(int a[],int n)
{
    int i;
    struct node *t, *last;
    first = new struct node;
    first->data = a[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    last=first;
 
    for (i=1;i<n;i++){
        t=new node;
        t->data=a[i];
        t->next=NULL;
        last->next=t;
        last=t;
    }
}

void display(struct node *p){
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<<p->data<<" ";
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    int A[] = {3,5,7,10,15};
    create(A,5);
    display(first);
}
```

error message:

```
Program 'Node.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:83
+ ... inked lists\" ; if ($?) { g++ Node.cpp -o Node } ; if ($?) { 
.\Node }
+                                                                  
~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:83
+ ... inked lists\" ; if ($?) { g++ Node.cpp -o Node } ; if ($?) { 
.\Node }
+                                                                  
~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], 
ApplicationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

This is error is shows after running code. After I run any program an `.exe` file is created but here the `.exe` file gets deleted by my antivirus because it says it is a trojan...

If I run code in an online compiler it works perfectly

Comment: What happens when you disable your anti-virus?

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: i havent tried yet but all other programs i run on same vs code with av on runs perfectly

Comment: Side note: once you get the tools issue sorted out, consider making a linked list class to manage the linked list. It usually makes your life easier.

Comment: You need to add your working directory to the A/V as an exception.  Normally it doesn't like new EXE files appearing on your system without running an installer.  Other programs you compile does work you say (I'm not sure what you are saying)?  Maybe it doesn't like the file name or something.  BTW, that looks like C + cout, not C++ at all.

Comment: Report this to the vendor of your antivirus. Include the program source code and the exe.

Comment: Your code look more like C than C++. In C++, one would write `node *p` (without `struct` keyword) and variable would generally be initiallized at their first use (for ex. `node *t=new node;`). Also global variables like `first` are usually avoided.

Comment: Why write your own Linked List when the STL has a nice Templated Linked List, use the algorithms to perform often used operations

Comment: Consider using `std::forward_list`, `std::list` or `std::vector` instead of writing your own container. By the way, your code has some **memory leaks**.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want to do is compile and run you can just do
`g++ Node.cpp -o Node ; .\Node`

if you want to make sure program doesn't run in case of compilation error you can do `g++ Node.cpp -o Node && .\Node`

if these don't work try running these commands in run in administration mode

Also your command is not clear please repost your full command again or post a screenshot of the command line